reCAPTCHA missing in webform
We have built a Drupal webform with ten pages, each containing one question. The last page includes both a question and a captcha. Users can check the captcha and submit the form. We are using Ajax settings within the webform for navigating between pages. The issue with reCAPTCHA arises when it is added to any pages other than the first page. reCAPTCHA functions correctly when placed on the first page.
When we replace reCAPTCHA with math (from the captcha module), it works fine on any page. reCAPTCHA was functioning properly until we recently upgraded to Drupal version 10.2.7; we are uncertain if this upgrade caused the issue.
The reCAPTCHA disappears when Ajax is enabled in the form settings. We are seeking a solution to ensure reCAPTCHA works on the last page of the web form.
reCAPTCHA working fine when added on the first page.

reCAPTCHA is missing when placed on any other page.

Ajax settings
[

Are there browser console errors?

@monalisa There are no errors in the browser console log.

THis your issue? https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha/issues/2493183 seems to be a patch on there

@unusedspoon That patch is not working.
